# Store current SAS title, change it temporarily, and restore it at end of macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've written a macro %xl to print an Excel file from a dataset with specific formatting. It is working fine by itself. However, the macro needs to set the `title` temporarily. I can clear the title at the end of the macro, but I really want to preserve the pre-macro title and restore it as the last step of my macro.

How can I capture the current value of `title` into a macro variable? Similar to %sysfunc(GetOption()) with options.

Thanks,
pT

Comment: Honestly, `title` is not something I think should be expected to be unchanged by a user.  Each PROC run should have its own title statement; if you have a title or portion of title you want consistent, save that in a macro variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Titles and footnotes can be retrieved using the SASHELP.VTITLE view.  So I would use that to save the current values, run your program, then run another step to reset the titles using `call execute`, like this:

```
data _old_titles;
  set sashelp.vtitle;
run;

/* do something */
footnote;
title;

/* reset titles and footnotes */
data _null_;
   set _old_titles;
   if type = 'T'
      then cmd = catt('title',number," '",trim(text)," ';");
      else cmd = catt('footnote',number," '",trim(text)," ';");
  call execute(cmd);
run;
```

Notice there is an extra blank used after the `text` value to prevent two consecutive apostrophes, which would translate into a single quote.  Also not the use of single quotes to prevent any unwanted macro expansion.

Not perfect, but remember that you can have many titles and footnotes, so an option or SAS system function would be difficult to create.  This has been a "feature request" many times but never implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like instead of first setting the title and then trying to create a macro variable from it, you'd be better off first setting a macro variable (or multiple if there are several different titles you'll want to use repeatedly), then using that in the title statement, like this:

```
%let title_text = "This is my pre-macro title";

/* Set title first time. */
title "&title_text";

/* Call macro. */
%xl;

/* Restore title. */
title "&title_text";
```

Comment: I agree that that would work, but it requires the outer code to know that the macro is going to change the title. I'm looking for a method that I can write entirely within %xl so that the (existing) outer code can function as it did before adding the call to %xl.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SAS/AF licensed you can create an SCL program to do what you want.  Follow instructions [here](http://support.sas.com/rnd/papers/sgf07/sgf2007-af.pdf) on creating a SCL program.

in your SCL program (I named mine gettitle.scl) you want

```
init:                                  
   call symput('TitleOld',gettitle(1));                                  
return;
```

After you compile this you can call it like this

```
title "whatever it happens to be";
proc display c=myscl.catalog.gettitle.scl; run;

%xl;

title "&TitleOld";
```